# How do I send a binary mp3 from google text to speech api from my server to my client using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

How do I send a binary mp3 data from google text to speech api from my server to my client using nodejs. The sound just didnt play.

Client (Javascript + Vuejs)

```
console.log(sound)
var audio = new Audio("data:audio/mpeg;base64," + sound);
audio.play();
```

This how the file look like when console.log the audio files(response.audioContent) sent from my server to my browser. Is the data correct?

[image]

Server (Nodejs + Firebase)

```
exports.speak = FirebaseFunc.https.onCall( asyncMiddleware( async (input, context) => {
    console.log("Speak  la")
    // Creates a client
    const client = new GTextToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();

    // The text to synthesize
    const text = 'Hello, world!';

    // Construct the request
    const request = {
        input: {text: text},
        // Select the language and SSML Voice Gender (optional)
        voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
        // Select the type of audio encoding
        audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
    };

    // Performs the Text-to-Speech request
    const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);

    return await { status: 200, message: "Successful", audio: response.audioContent }
}))
```

Comment: "This is what I get when I inspect and console.log from my browser. Is the data correct?"  What exactly are you inspecting/logging?

Comment: its the audio file from my server. response.audioContent

Comment: That's not helpful.  What exactly did you run `console.log()` on?  What variable here from your code?

Comment: Hi i console.log(sound)
var audio = new Audio("data:audio/mpeg;base64," + sound);
audio.play();